# anonymous class extending an abstract class

Tags: java, anonymous-types

I'm looking to schedule a task at a specified time `startTime`, and when that time comes, 
i want it to run a method `rrun(boolean param1, Object someObj)`.

`rrun()` is a method in class, say `SomeClass`.

And, within `SomeClass` again, i have a method `m1()` that does this as part of its code:

```
    Timer startTimer = new Timer(); 


    startTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {rrun(false, this);}
                }, 
            startTime);
```

To this, i'm getting the error that

```
incompatible types: <anonymous TimerTask> cannot be converted to SomeClass
```

What's wrong with what i'm doing?

TIA.

//===============================

EDIT:

I'm using JDK 8 -- the latest one

Comment: what is your java compiler?

Comment: @VictorSorokin jdk 8

Comment: Sorry for irrelevant question, issue is nailed down by rgettman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the anonymous inner class, `this` is a reference to the current `TimerTask` anonymous subclass, not the enclosing class.

To refer to the enclosing class, qualify `this`:

```
public void run() {rrun(false, SomeClass.this);}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need more code than this. What does rrun take as arguments?

My guess is you want this though:

```
public void run() {rrun(false, SomeClass.this);}
```